# How to ignore hot updates for some files in Vue CLI v5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-5

In the `/public` folder, I have some configuration files. When I update these files, I don't want to watch their changes for hot updates.I tried to set up the configuration here according to the webpack configuration, but it didn't work, How can I configure this?

Comment: `I tried to set up` - show what you tried

Comment: Like this

 devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      watch: false,
    },
  }